# Could not find a part of the path ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have made a site in which there is a folder named `Zipfile` from which i want to access `LSC.exe` file to download.When i click on the path it gives following exception `System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\~\Zipfile\LSC.exe'.`

Any suggestions please.

**controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public FileResult downloadFile()
{
    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("~/Zipfile/LSC.exe");
    string fileName = "SkypeSetup.exe";
    return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to Add Server.MapPath(exe path)
in order to get map to its relative path

```
  byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/Zipfile/LSC.exe"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use **Server.MapPath** to map to the files under the application directory.

Reference: [HttpServerUtility.MapPath Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
public FileResult downloadFile()
    {
     byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/Zipfile/LSC.exe"));
        string fileName = "SkypeSetup.exe";
        return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
    }
```